# INSERT INTO SELECT MAX From Another Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement that right now has a static number. I'd like to make this number dynamic by making it the `MAX` of a field from another table.

The statement is:

```
INSERT INTO checklist_items (checklists_id, checklist_item_types_id, is_completed)
    SELECT 3, cit.id, false
    FROM checklist_item_types cit
    WHERE cit.is_active = 't'
```

Here's a sample of each of the tables:

Here is my `checklists` table:

```
id  checklist_date  notes
1   "2018-07-23"    "Fixed extra stuff"
2   "2018-07-24"    "These are some extra notes"
3   "2018-07-25"    "Notes notes"
```

Here is my `checklist_items` table, data reduced:

```
id  checklists_id  checklists_item_types_id  is_completed
1   1              1                         false
2   1              2                         true
3   1              3                         true
...
34  2              16                        true
35  2              17                        true
36  2              18                        true
```

And here is `checklist_item_types`, data reduced:

```
id  description                        is_active
1   "Unlock Entrances"                 true
2   "Ladies Locker Room Lights"        true
3   "Check Hot Tubs (AM)"              true
...
15  "Water Softener Boiler Room"       false
16  "Water Softener Laundry"           true
17  "Check/Stock Fire Logs"            true
18  "Drain Steam Lines (4 locations)"  true
```

How do I go about changing `SELECT 3` to something like `SELECT MAX(checklists.id)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply replace the `3` with a `subquery`:

```
INSERT INTO checklist_items (checklists_id, checklist_item_types_id, is_completed)
    SELECT (SELECT MAX(id) FROM checklists), cit.id, false
    FROM checklist_item_types cit
    WHERE cit.is_active = 't'
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm unsure what you mean? It added 17 records as expected (18 `checklist_item_types` minus 1 because `is_active` is `false` for that 1).

Comment: @WolfieeifloW "I'm unsure what you mean?" never mind i didn't notice the MAX function used it's own subquery so this query is perfect valid.

Answer (score 1):

YOu could use an inner join and group by

```
  INSERT INTO checklist_items (checklists_id, checklist_item_types_id, is_completed)
      SELECT max(c.id), cit.id, false as status
      FROM checklist_item_types cit
      INNER JOIN checklists c  ON c.id =  cid.checklists_id
      WHERE cit.is_active = 't'
      group by  cit.id, status
```